# Aplicar icon consoante o valor de texto na célula

Tags: planilha

Assumindo como exemplo a coluna `E`, cuja mesma contém o valor `Sim` ou o valor `Não`, estou a tentar criar uma formatação condicional que aplique uma seta consoante o texto presente na própria célula:

```
Sim   = Verde
Não   = Vermelho  
outro = Amarelo
```

A questão é que isto não parece funcionar com texto, apenas com números porque por defeito já assume uma comparação `>=`.

#### Se utilizar números, obtenho o resultado pretendido:

[image: Formatação Condicional com base numérica]

Que resulta em:

[image: Resultado da Formatação Condicional com base numérica]

Mas o problema é que `-1`, `0` e `1` não são humanamente legíveis (salvo para o programador...).

## Pergunta

No [Libre Office Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/), como aplicar uma seta automaticamente com base num valor de texto presente na própria célula?

<sup>Se impossível, uma alternativa aceitável passa por aplicar uma formatação posterior à formatação condicional onde o valor `1` seja apresentado como `Sim`, e o valor `-1` como `Não`.</sup>

Exemplo da folha de cálculo: [exemplo.ods](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B312FJ_hQfOrbmF1TEotLVpSQzA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Você tentou usar uma fórmula que "traduz" o texto automaticamente para 1, -1 ou 0 (por exemplo, usando a [função `SE`](http://www.ubuntudicas.com.br/blog/2011/11/funcao-se-libreoffice/))? Aliás, você poderia compartilhar um exemplo mínimo da planilha, só pra facilitar os testes de quem for ajudar. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira Adicionei uma folha de calculo exemplificativa. A função `SE` ainda não experimentei, vou testar isso. Tks!

Comment: Eu tava testando aqui, mas parece que ele aplica a formatação condicional só que não exibe quando o conteúdo é texto. Fiz o seguinte teste: apliquei a formatação na coluna usando uma fórmula que referencia a coluna seguinte; ele não exibe os ícones, mas se eu mudo o valor de uma célula pra numérico, dai então ele exibe o ícone. Parece que a minha sugestão não vai funcionar, porque o recurso é só pra células de valor numérico... :(

Comment: @LuizVieira Os meus testes antes de colocar a pergunta também me fizeram chegar a essa conclusão...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema parece ser realmente o fato de que esse tipo de formatação condicional (*Icon Set*) só funcionar para tipos de dados numéricos. Mas não achei confirmação oficial para essa suspeita em lugar algum da Internet (apenas achei indicação de que é impossível usar um conjunto customizado de ícones, porque [a imagem é compilada junto ao código fonte do LibreOffice](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/31172/create-my-own-conditional-icon-sets/?answer=31181#post-id-31181)).

Enfim, descobri uma forma de fazer o que você quer com a alternativa que você mesmo sugeriu: usar na célula realmente os valores numéricos, mas exibí-los ao usuário na forma de texto. Para isso, basta criar novos estilos específicos para os textos "Sim", "Não" e "Outros".

1. Abra a janela de Estilos, acessando o menu "Formatar" (*Format*) -> "Estilos e Formatação" (*Styles and Formatting*) - no meu LibreOffice, que está em inglês, a tecla de atalho é <kbd>F11</kbd>.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. Nessa janela, clique com o botão direito do mouse sobre o estilo base (*Default*) e selecione novo. Você vai precisar criar um estilo para cada valor discreto dos seus dados (isto é, um para "Sim", um para "Não" e um para "Outros" - como no seu exemplo). Dê o nome ao seu estilo na aba principal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3. Na aba "Números" (*Numbers*), selecione na categoria o formato definido pelo usuário (*User-defined*, no meu caso em inglês) e digite a string que deseja que apareça (entre aspas!) no campo do código de formatação (*Format code*). Clique Ok e esse estilo estará gravado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

4. Faça o mesmo para todos os estilos. No final você vai ter algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

5. Agora, vá na coluna de dados que você deseja formatar (que, naturalmente, deverão conter os valores numéricos 1, 0 ou -1 ao invés de texto) e adicione normalmente a formatação condicional de ícones (Icon Set) que você já estava usando. Então, clique em "Adicionar" (*Add*) para incluir uma nova formatação simples, escolhendo o valor e o estilo a ser aplicado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

6. Repita para todos os valores/estilos possíveis (no seu exemplo, ao final você vai ter 4 condições simultâneas: a dos icones, e 1 para cada possível texto "Sim", "Não" e "Outros"). Depois de aplicado, os seus dados vão ser exibidos como você deseja, muito embora o valor das células ainda seja numérico (como você pode perceber pelo número exibido ali em cima, onde indicado em vermelho).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Impecável, um pouco trabalhoso, mas como é reutilizável, Impecável! :)

Comment: Lembre-se que você também pode aplicar o estilo (de texto, não a formatação condicional de ícones) manualmente a uma célula usando a função style em uma fórmula. Como ela retorna sempre 0, você pode fazer, por exemplo: =1+Style("Sim"). Ai só precisa deixar fixa a formatação condicional de ícones. O resto você controla ao atualizar as células. :)